# AWS Lambda is writing wrong output in the CloudWatch metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I'm new to Devops and coding. I'm working on building a monitoring tool (grafana) with CloudWatch and Lambda.

I have a code which is not working properly. It pings the server. If it is returning 200 it will push 0 in the metrics and when the site is down it should push 1 but when I'm mentioning in the write metrics to write 1, instead of writing 1 its writing 100 and if I try to do any other values its greater than 100 its posting but less than 100 its just post 100.

Here is the code:

```
import boto3

import urllib2

def write_metric(value, metric):

    d = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    d.put_metric_data(Namespace='WebsiteStatus',
                      MetricData=[
                          {
                      'MetricName':metric,
                      'Dimensions':[
                          {
                      'Name': 'Status',
                      'Value': 'WebsiteStatusCode',
                          },
                          ],
                      'Value': value,
    },
    ]
                      )

def check_site(url, metric):

    STAT = 1
    print("Checking %s " % url)
    request = urllib2.Request("https://" +url)

    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        response.close()
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        if hasattr(e, 'code'):
            print ("[Error:] Connection to %s failed with code: " %url +str(e.code))
            STAT = 100
            write_metric(STAT, metric)
        if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            print ("[Error:] Connection to %s failed with code: " % url +str(e.reason))
            STAT = 100
            write_metric(STAT, metric)
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        if hasattr(e, 'code'):
            print ("[Error:] Connection to %s failed with code: " % url + str(e.code))
            STAT = 100
            write_metric(STAT, metric)
        if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            print ("[Error:] Connection to %s failed with code: " % url + str(e.reason))
            STAT = 100
            write_metric(STAT, metric)
        print('HTTPError!!!')

    if STAT != 100:
        STAT = response.getcode()

    return STAT

def lambda_handler(event, context):


    websiteurls = [
        "website.com"
    ]
    metricname = 'SiteAvailability'

    for site in websiteurls:
        r = check_site(site,metricname)
        if r == 200:
            print("Site %s is up" %site)
            write_metric(0, metricname)
        else:
            print("[Error:] Site %s down" %site)
            write_metric(1, metricname)
```

Comment: Why don't you add a print statement to write_metric() so that you can be sure you know exactly what metrics your code is pushing.

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
        STAT = 100
        write_metric(STAT, metric)
```

will *always* send `100` as your value.